# Are there any LaTeX IDEs which provide useful error messages?

Tags: compiling, editors, compilation-error, ide

I was using `TeXworks` as my source code editor and I got my actual `LaTeX` compiler and packages through `MikTeX`.

I executed the following code block:

```
\begin {enumerate} % WEAK
\item $G$ is a function such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $G(x) = x$
\item $F$ is a function such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $F(x) = x$
\item $x = y = 1$
\end {eumerate}
```

The compiler not only did not provide an error message, but got stuck in an infinite loop. It ran for a couple of minutes until I killed it.

The error is on the last line:
In my `\end` statement. There's a missing letter `n` in `eumerate`

Are there any `LaTeX` IDEs that will say something useful, like:

> Line 288. unknown environment "eumerate". Did you mean "enumerate"
>   instead?

Comment: TeXworks is actually one of the best as it does show you the *log output* (unshortened).

Comment: Normally tex wouldn't loop with this input, you would get the error `! LaTeX Error: \begin{enumerate} on input line 5 ended by \end{eumerate}.`.

Comment: any editor with decent syntax highlighting should be able to spot that and mark it as an error even without compiling the latex code. I'm partial to texstudio myself.

Comment: also, most if not all tex editors don't supply custom error messages, as far as I can tell. they usually extract from the log file, which is of course, produced by tex itself, independent of the editor. so again, any decent tex editor which gives (easy) access to the log file will suit your needs nicely.

Comment: as Ulrike says error messages come from tex not your editor, and latex does not loop on that input and gives quite a reasonable error message. so it is hard to understand your question. If latex was looping then there was an error in some other code that you have not shown. Pleae alwyas provide a test file that reproduces an error, then it is easy for someone to debug

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You did not provide a test file that reproduces an infinite loop. If I complete your fragment to a document then LaTeX does not loop and the error highlights the typo in the environment name.  If you are getting a loop that will be due to an unrelated error elsewhere in your file.

From

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\begin {enumerate} % WEAK
\item $G$ is a function such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $G(x) = x$
\item $F$ is a function such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $F(x) = x$
\item $x = y = 1$
\end {eumerate}

\end{document}
```

LaTeX reports:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{enumerate} on input line 5 ended by \end{eumerate}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \end {eumerate}

?
```

Of course the error from LaTeX is independent of the editor that you use to write the input file, so I wrote this test file in emacs but you would get the same if you had written it in TeXWorks.

Comment: Although not the case for TeXworks some editors severely 'censor' the error reporting or badly mangle the display of it  so although the log errors will of course be the same the displayed content might not be.  TeXStudio is one of those I think.